# ValueError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 9 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to extract the table in this [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Glasgow_Subway_stations) for a capstone project I'm trying to do.

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
ValueError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 9 columns
```

Code:

```
url =requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Glasgow_Subway_stations').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())

arrond_table = soup.find('table', class_='wikitable sortable')
arrond_table_rows = arrond_table.find_all('tr')


information = []
for row in arrond_table_rows:
    info = row.text.split('\n')[1:-1]
    information.append(info)

del information[0][1::2]

information


arrond_df = pd.DataFrame(information[2:],columns = information[0])
arrond_df.head(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

`pd.DataFrame()` requires the same number of columns between the data and the column names otherwise a `ValueError` will be thrown.

---

Coming to your problem now,

```
arrond_df = pd.DataFrame(information[2:],columns = information[0])
```

the error clearly indicates that your data (`information[2:]`) has 9 columns in total but the column names that you provide (`columns=information[0]`) are only 5.

Make sure you provide sufficient column names for your data.

In other words, the following condition should apply

```
information[2:].shape[1] == len(columns)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! Modified the code a lil bit and it works now. Cheers !